# Where can I find the SQL queries for use with OpenStreetMap-Carto?

Tags: openstreetmap, cartocss

I found the OpenStreetMap-carto stylesheets (`.mss`files) [here](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto). I also found an issue discussing a problem with a SQL query [here](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/issues/939).  Does anyone know where I can find the SQL scripts to build the layers in TileMill? Maybe a TileMill project?

Answer (score 1):

SQL queries themselves are part of carto-css project. You can find them [here](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/project.yaml#L111)